# Unable to connect to servicenow

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, servicenow

I am facing below error when trying to connect to servicenow suing json. Code i am trying to run is:

```
from servicenow import ServiceNow
from servicenow import Connection

conn = Connection.Auth(username='admin.main', password='Rusty123#', instance='abcd.servicenow.com')
inc = inc.fetch_one({'number': 'INCV0346936'})
print inc

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='abcd.servicenow.com.service-now.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //incident.do?JSON=&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_query=number%3DINCV0346936 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002183FE7D388>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Has this python code ever worked once?
if it did, what changed since? Is your ServiceNow instance started?

The error `getaddrinfo failed`, means that the host can not be resolved. 
in your code you set `instance='abcd.servicenow.com'` but then the error shows

```
Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='abcd.servicenow.com.service-now.com'
```

See how the value of the variable instance was prefixed to `.service-now.com`?

To fix the error, change the value of the instance to only the name of your own instance: `abcd`

FYI, In the URL www.servicenow.com:

- servicenow.com is the Domain name
- www is the Subdomain name for ServiceNow
- abcd is the Subdomain name for your own ServiceNow instance

Answer (score 0):

Look at the response

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='abcd.servicenow.com.service-now.com', port=443)'))
```

you need to enter just the instance name as the program is already including the URL after.

Change:

```
conn = Connection.Auth(username='admin.main', password='Rusty123#', instance='abcd.servicenow.com')
```

To:

```
conn = Connection.Auth(username='admin.main', password='Rusty123#', instance='abcd')
```